# Opening Matlab with target directory specified?

Tags: matlab, windows-8.1

I am running several Matlab instances (Windows 8.1). Is it possible to create a shortcut that would open each instance with different startup directory selected?

Comment: On what operating system?

Comment: Running Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Create multiple shortcuts of your Matlab exe. Then for each shortcut, right click, go to properties and set the starting directory to a different folder.

**Edit by Danijel:**

In Matlab open Home/Preferences/General and set "Initial working folder" to "Location based on MATLAB startup rules". If this is set to something different like "Last working folder" then this solution doesn't work.

Comment: Maybe it's worth to point out that this works only on Windows, even if it's kinda explicit with the `.exe` part.

Comment: Yes, it is only for windows. It works on my computer.

Comment: This works under one condition: open Home/Preferences/General and set "Initial working folder" to "Location based on MATLAB startup rules". If this is set to something different like "Last working folder" then the above solution doesn't work. Please add this to your answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Great, I didn't know this.